# Programmatically access iMessages

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, imessage

I use xamarin but any answer related to this would help.

Is it possible to access iMessages on a device, with the users permission obviously.

I know I can send iMessages programmatically but have a requirement to actually access the iMessages stored on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Apple does not provide any public API to access Messages.

Comment: @iwayneo Dear God man, you think that would be a good idea? An app having access to your private messages?

Comment: @ErikKerber LOL!! even if it was just for me.. I had to go back through years of iMessages recently and it kept crashing when I got to a certain point. was so painful.

Comment: Had the same issue.  Searching with the default app is PAINFUL!!  I too wanted to write something that could inspect that info.  No dice I guess.